# Trouble executing Java file in command prompt

Tags: java, cmd, jersey

I'm having a problem with a project I'm working on. When I execute it using

> intellij

it goes fine, but when I try to run it using command prompt an error shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSrJH.png) appears. Can anybody please help me?

[image]

I use Jersey version 1.12 and the following JARs:

```
activation-1.1.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
comresrcgen-1.0.jar
FastInfoset-1.2.12.jar
grizzly-servlet-webserver-1.9.45.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jersey-bundle-1.12.jar
jersey-bundle-1.9.jar
jersey-client-1.12.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-core-1.12.jar
jersey-grizzly-1.12.jar
jersey-multipart-1.12.jar
jersey-multipart-1.9.jar
 jersey-server.jar
 jettison-1.1.jar
  localizer-1.0.jar
 mail-1.4.4.jar
  mimepull-1.3.jar
 persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
  rome-1.0.jar
  stax-api-1.0-2.jar
  wadl-cmdline-1.1.2.jar
  wadl-core-1.1.2.jar
```

Comment: you need to add dependecy library in path when run command prompt.javac -classpath path/to/library1.jar Main.java

Comment: @mithatkonuk i use the java -cp .;"../../../lib/*" ser.Server command to run it but still not working :/ is that wrong ? coz it gives the error as shown in the picture but doesnt gives error for the other jars (in the beginning it shows the list of all the jars found at lib folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven on your project, execute this on the command line or terminal inside intellij:

```
mvn clean package
```

this will create a jar file on your project's target folder. Now you can run that jar on the commandline:

```
java -jar your-project.jar
```

Update:
If and if your project is not maven based, intelliJ can convert it for you. Right click your project folder on left panel or where your project pane is located, scroll down to "Maven" then click "Show effective POM". It will generate a pom file for you "-effective-pom.xml". Rename and save it to pom.xml on the project root folder, then you can do the steps mentioned above.

Comment: but i think he is not using maven , given classpath with command prompt

Comment: @leo as mithatkonuk said i'm not using maven. is there any other way?  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: in intellij go to: **File | Project Structure | Artifacts - add (+) - JAR - From modules with dependencies** and specify your main class. Then **Build | Build Artifacts** and choose your artifact. Now you should be able to run it from command line.

Comment: @lenny still not working :/ i use the java -cp .;"../../../lib/*" ser.Server command to run it. is that wrong ? coz it gives the error as shown in the picture but doesnt gives error for the other jars

Comment: @Anja.M to run the jar file generated from the artifact you have to use the command which Leo already mentioned.